# When I try to start session - Am facing this type of issue on Appium [On provided some capabilities]

Tags: appium

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device platform version. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' -P 5037 -s RWCIKB6DFEMB4LGE shell getprop ro.build.version.release' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'adb.exe: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.'; Code: '1'

REf:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XcCl.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if your device is authorized: `adb devices`

If its not authorized then that helped me:

1. Disconnect USB between PC and device
2. Stop adb server by entering "adb kill-server" in command window
3. On device use "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" in "Developer Options"
4. Reconnect the device to the PC
5. Open a command window and enter "adb devices". Watch the device's screen for any Authorization message and allow the connection.